# Facing issues integrating Facebook stream.share Dialog Box

Tags: facebook, stream, share

Facing issue while implementing share dialog box.

If I specify Facebook post URL I don't get the proper image, description on dialog box
Just displaying the url: http://www.facebook.com/132203113509196/posts/441790742550430

Current Snippet using for share dialog box.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'stream.share',
    u: post_url,
}, function(response){ console.log(response); }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that´s not how it works, there are no Open Graph tags in that url. Also, i think "stream.share" is deprecated, better use "feed":

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Of course you have to define all the parameters by yourself, but it makes it pretty flexible too. You can, for example, just read the data with the Graph API and use it for the feed dialog:

> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=132203113509196_441790742550430

Comment: Thanks luschn, while specifying fb cdn image url in feed dialog box, it is throwing error :- FBCDN image is not allowed in stream:. Is there any alternative for it.

Comment: oh, did not think about that...well, you could download the image to your server and use the absolute url...but the image has to stay on the server then.